# Redirect a file from one server to another ftp server via nginx

Tags: linux, ftp, nginx

I am using ftp linux command to send files from one server to another. Now i am trying to do the same but nginx will be the middle man between both the servers.

Suppose i have 2 servers A and B and a third server C which is an nginx server.

Previously i have redirected normal http request from server A to B via server C.
Now i want to do the same but i want to send file from server A to C which will then redirect the ftp connection to server B.

So is it possible ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain (in detail) what the issue you are encountering is.

Answer (score 0):

NGINX can't handle FTP connections.

You'd need to create a wrapper website which calls ftp command for the file transfer from/to server B. This can be accomplished using [fastcgi](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html).